# Diferencia entre "por eso" y "por ello"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "por eso" y "por ello"?
- ¿Existen casos en el que se puede usar uno y no el otro?

Ejemplo:

> Estaba lloviendo; por eso / por ello no pude ir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

También puedes utilizar `por aquello` cuando te quieres referir a algo lejano en el tiempo al momento actual. Ejemplo:

> Por aquello (que ocurrió), me tuve que ir.

Todas son equivalentes (`por eso, por esto, por ello y por aquello`) cuando quieres expresar la causa de una acción ocurrida. 
`Por eso` y `por esto` son muy similares y se pueden usar indistintamente.

La sutil diferencia es el transcurso temporal de las acciones (`Por eso` y `por esto`, cercanos en el tiempo; `por aquello`, lejano en el tiempo).

`Por ello`, es más formal y no denota transcurso temporal.

Answer (score 2):

"Eso" es un demostrativo que hace referencia a una cosa conocida a una distancia relativamente corta, mientras que "ello" es un pronombre que hace referencia a una cosa que ya has nombrado. En la mayoría de los casos vas a poder usarlos por igual, pero no son completamente intercambiables.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas son equivalentes. `Por ello` es más formal, y es más común oírlo en conferencias, por ejemplo, pero se pueden usar indistintamente.

También tienes `Por esto`, que es formal y se suele emplear al principio de la frase:

> Por esto, celebramos la convención.

Answer (score 1):

Alguna vez leí en algún lado que no se debe emplear una palabra rebsuscada por sólo pretender ser erudito. En relación con este asunto, he notado que algunos comentaristas y conductores de radio y televisión abusan del "por ello", tal vez por aquello de que "es más formal". Sin embargo esos mismos personajes, que por otro lado constantemente mencionan sus estudios universitarios, suelen cometer repetidamente errores tales como el mal empleo del género y del número.

Comment: Hola Luis, ¡bienvenido al sitio y gracias por tu contribución! 
Fíjate que la pregunta intenta averiguar sobre la diferenciación de los significados. Tu observación sobre el abuso del término y la característica de los que lo emplean es una referencia indirecta, o lateral al problema planteado. Fijate que puedes editarla y mejorarla para aumentar su relevancia como respuesta